# RRD Tool Graph Highlight NAN value

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

Is there a way that I can have rrdGraph create a graph that highlights any missing data, rather than just leaving that space blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `CDEF` using the `UN` and `IF` commands to detect unknown data and turn it into INF which you could then paint using the `AREA` function to fill the background of the chart. Smokeping uses this trick.

Comment: That sounds complicated :)  I will give it a shot and see where it takes me, I may be back looking for sample code though!

Comment: Sorry for the suspense, but I did finally get it.  Exactly what I wanted to do was 2/3 of the way down the page on the rrdTool CDEF tutorial.  [http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/cdeftutorial.en.html](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/cdeftutorial.en.html)

Answer (score 3):

Test the variable for unknown, and set a CDEF to be infinity if it is and 0 otherwise.

```
DEF:in=myfile.rrd:ds0
LINE1:in#0000ff:My_data
CDEF:unavailable=in,UN,INF,0,IF
AREA:unavailable#d0d0d0
```

Make sure your AREA comes after the LINE if you want it to blank out the graph when things are unknown.  Expand the CDEF if you want to check multiple variables for unknown-ness.

Comment: Now I just need to do this in ~3000 Cacti graph templates :(
Would be very handy as an rrdgraph option.